# What is question score

Tags: support, badges, score

I read the math FAQ and searched meta.math. [Some badges](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/24/good-answer) are awarded for answering a question with score 25 (or other number) or more. What is a question's "score"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The score of a question or answer is the number displayed on the upper left, that indicates the total number of upvotes it received minus the total number of downvotes it received. For example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real) has received 219 upvotes and 28 downvotes, giving it its current score of 191. Since its score is 100 or greater, its asker received a [Great Question badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/22/great-question). Similarly with answers: [this answer to the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54568/264) received 324 upvotes and 1 downvote, giving it its current score of 323. Since its score is 100 or greater, its poster received a [Great Answer badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/25/great-answer).

By the way, one gains the ability to see the separate upvote and downvote counts [with a reputation of at least 1000](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user).